# What's wrong with my Verilog multiplexer?

Tags: verilog

I created a 2-way 4-bit multiplexer:

```
module mux2(c, x, y, m);
  input c;
  input [3:0] x;
  input [3:0] y;
  output [9:0] m;

  assign m[3:0] = (~c & x) | (c & y);
  assign m[9:4] = 0;
endmodule
```

I instantiated it from my top-level module:

```
module top(SW, LEDR);
  input [9:0] SW;
  output [9:0] LEDR;

  mux2 mymux(SW[9], SW[3:0], SW[7:4], LEDR[9:0]);
endmodule
```

I did a functional simulation in Altera Quartus Prime Lite on a Cyclone V 5CSEMA5F31C6 (having imported assignments from [DE1_SoC.qsf](ftp://ftp.altera.com/up/pub/Altera_Material/Boards/DE1-SoC/DE1_SoC.qsf)) and got this unexpected waveform:

[image: collapsed waveform]

As expected, the output M follows X when C is low; however, M does not follow Y when C is high. Instead, it seems to have a combination of X and Y values.

Here is an expanded version of the previous waveform:

[image: expanded waveform]

I assume I'm instantiated mux2 incorrectly but don't see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
assign m[3:0] = (~c & x) | (c & y);
```

you should use a ternary operator like so

```
assign m[3:0] = c ? y : x;
```

Alternatively, you can expand c to be the same width as x and y like so:

```
assign m[3:0] = (~{4{c}} & x) | ({4{c}} & y);
```

Noe that the ternary operator is much more concise.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Assuming that's for correctness, not style, how would it explain my results?

Comment: c is only 1 bit wide.  So your code always passes through x[3:1] and only switches the lowest order bit.